# Creating an RSS2 feed, looks fine but doesn't work?

Tags: php, rss

I'm trying to create an RSS feed which reads out the threads from my forum into an RSS feed. The address of the feed is http://romhackersonline.com/forum/external2.php And I validated it and checked the source, it looks fine. The problem is it refuses to show any content or description on any RSS reader.

Can anyone have a look at the source and see if I've missed something? I can provide code if needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PHP header

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8"); ?>
```

Comment: Added it and it still refuses to show anything for content or description on readers, yet still validates and shows correct data in the source.

Comment: [Read up on this](http://www.stevenyork.com/tutorial/how_to_configure_htaccess_allow_php_access_with_xml_extension) OR [This related tutorial](http://www.seopher.com/articles/writing_a_php_google_sitemap_generator_without_using_fopen)